# Stop shell script sending repeated emails - using file flag

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My requirement is to send an email if I find a string in a log file; however, I should be sending it only once.  The shell script I have written is pasted below; however, it is sending repeated emails via cron job even when the condition is not matching.

```
#!/bin/bash
filexists=""
lbdown=""`enter code here`
if [ -f "/var/run/.mailsenttoremedy" ];
then
   filexists=true
else
   filexists=false
echo filexists is $filexists
fi

if tail -1000 /usr/ibm/tivoli/common/CTGIM/logs/trace.log | grep "Root exception is java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host"
then
    echo error found
        lbdown=true
echo lbdown status after if in tail is $lbdown
else
lbdown=false
echo lbdown status after else in tail is $lbdown 
fi

if filexists=false && lbdown=true
then
{
mailx -S intrelay.sysco.com -r xxx@yyy.com -s "**DEV ALERT**Load Balancer Connection not Available" -v xxx@yyy.com < /dev/null
date > /var/run/.mailsenttoremedy
}
fi

if filexists=true && lbdown=true
then
{
echo MAIL ALREADY SENT
}
fi

if lbdown=false
then
rm -f /var/run/.mailsenttoremedy
fi
echo lbdown is $lbdown and filexists is $filexists
```

echo outputs are:

```
filexists is false
Root exception is java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
error found
lbdown status after if in tail is true
Null message body; hope that's ok
Mail Delivery Status Report will be mailed to <xxx@yyy.com>.
MAIL ALREADY SENT
lbdown is false and filexists is true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a normal declaration for the `if` requests...

**Bash format:**

```
if [ $(tail -1000 /usr/ibm/tivoli/common/CTGIM/logs/trace.log | grep "Root exception is java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host") != "" ];
then

if  [ "$filexists" = "false" ] && [ "$lbdown" = "true" ];
then

if [ "$lbdown" = "false" ];
then
```

Test commands via `if` should be surrounded by `[` and `]`, at least the ones with multiple conditions. Here is a [guide for `if` and some sample codes](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) if you are interested.

In addition, variables need a `$` in front of them at least. Normally they are surrounded by `{` and `}` too.

PS. You could use a better format for the post so people won't downvote you.

Comment: I took the liberty of replacing all the "u"s with "you"s.

Comment: thanks for the effort and I will get better, promise !

Comment: I finally made it work, thanks.  It puzzles me that if you declare the if wrong, shell would not throw a syntax error but instead allow everything to pass inside.

Comment: Please pardon my formatting as this was my first question posted here.

Answer (score 0):

For others, the working code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
filexists=""
lbdown=""
if [ -f "/var/run/.mailsenttoremedy" ];
then
   filexists=true
else
   filexists=false
echo filexists is $filexists
fi

if tail -1000 /usr/ibm/tivoli/common/CTGIM/logs/trace.log | grep "nn"
then
    echo error found
        lbdown=true
echo lbdown status after if in tail is $lbdown
else
lbdown=false
echo lbdown status after else in tail is $lbdown 
fi

if [[ "$filexists" = "false" && "$lbdown" = "true" ]];
then
mailx -S intrelay.sysco.com -r xxx@yyy.com -s "**DEV ALERT**Load Balancer Connection not Available" -v xxx@yyy.com < /dev/null
date > /var/run/.mailsenttoremedy
fi

if [[ "$filexists" = "true" && "$lbdown" = "true" ]];
then
echo MAIL ALREADY SENT
fi

if [ "$lbdown" = "false" ];
then
rm -f /var/run/.mailsenttoremedy
echo removing file
fi
echo lbdown is $lbdown and filexists is $filexists
```